# Can't open iAd on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, iad-workbench

I wanted to ask a question about iAd on iTunes Connect, When i Click iAd it's showing me a message, it's showing it about a week. Is it problem with my account or with Apple ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem. This is probably bug. If you want to see iAd report, you can access the following URL:

https://iad.apple.com/itcportal

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, same problem. It's a bug.

**Kosuke Ogawa**, I follow your link, but there is - "iAd network temporarily unavailable". I guess, we have to wait until apple fix it...